# DataProc Cluster Spark Job submission fails to start NodeManager

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

We have Dataproc cluster with 4 workers configured. Cluster is up and running and whenever we try to submit the spark-job we are getting this error:

```
YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager, Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeManager
```

Some of the messages seen in Stackdriver logs are

```
Daemon YARN_NODE_MANAGER failed to restart
```

**Update**:
This issue is noticed even while we add new worked node to the existing Dataproc cluster.

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager, Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeManager from <MasterNode DNS> , Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:912)
```

Comment: Have you made changes to the cluster or YARN configuration? Have you looked at the logs on Stackdriver?

Comment: Checked the logs, not sure, recreated the cluster and i dont see this error.

Comment: Similar issue is seen, if we add new worker node to the existing Cluster, after creating the cluster, whenever we resize it, on adding new node. Following errors are noticed.

Comment: `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager, Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeManager from <MasterNode DNS> , Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager. at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:374) at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:252) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error looks like a YARN node manager decommission problem. Can you check whether there is mistake on following YARN include/exclude node configuration file in Dataproc master GCE VM:

- /etc/hadoop/conf/nodes_exclude
- /etc/hadoop/conf/nodes_include

After change these config file, please run refresh node command:

```
yarn rmadmin -refreshNodes
```

Then you should expect to see the Nodemanager rejoin the YARN.

For details, please refer to:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/GracefulDecommission.html#nodeslistmanager-detects-and-handles-include-and-exclude-list-changes

Comment: thanks, it helped , there some issue with FQDN in the nodes_include file, after adding it manually and restarting the nodes were shown in YARN manager.